# Best practice for product groups in shopware

Tags: shopware

We want to create a new instance for an existing shop.

The current structure is always:

`Manufacturer -> product type -> product -> product group -> product`

example:
`AEG -> washer -> AEG 1018 Lavamatc -> tubes -> inlet tube`

Now my question is the following: 
What is the best practice to do this in shopware?

Manufacturer and products are clear but do I need to create categories for everything between? Or is there a better way or a plugin?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
Categories sound like the right way to do it though. Otherwise it gets harder to keep track of the structure.

Another way would be to use properties. These can be seen like Tags.
But if you want the customer to navigate though these sublevels you should really use Categories.